# I'm gonna listen it or I'm gonna TO listen it?

Tags: prepositions, infinitives, auxiliary-verbs, contractions, indirect-objects

What is the correct way of the following two options?

1) I'm gonna listen it
2) I'm gonna **TO** listen it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*gonna = going to*.

If you use the second one, you'll say <s>*I'm going to to listen it.*</s>

But you need to use *listen to,* so you get

> I'm gonna listen to it.

Answer (score 2):

gonna comes from "goin' 'a" which leaves a couple consonants out of "going ta" which is what "going to" sounds like in some informal speech.

So, "gonna to" is "going to to" and doesn't make sense.

Similarly, "wanna" is "wan' 'a" which is "want ta" and means "want to."

Comment: And yes, Subjunctive is right, you need a to after listen. "I'm gonna listen to it."